# rename multiple files bash in a subdir

Tags: bash, rename

I am trying to use rename but I have several subdirs.  The expression I am trying to use is this:

```
rename 's/ZAUQ-F24MS-SC12-F01-5C\/R44.wav/wav\/2012.wav/' *.wav
```

I want to rename the file `ZAUQ-F24MS-SC12-F01-5C/R44.wav` to `wav/2012.wav` and all files are `*.wav` files.

I am able to do this from inside the directory but I have multiple directories and a mapped to and from list.  Can rename do this or should I be using something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you are moving a file from one directory (`ZAUQ-F24MS-SC12-F01-5C`) to another (`wav`). Why not `mv` then:

```
mv ZAUQ-F24MS-SC12-F01-5C/R44.wav wav/2012.wav
```